# Two menu widgets in Asidefirst zone in Orchard CMS

Tags: widget, customization, orchardcms

According to design specification I have to add two different menu lists with own Titles on `AsideFirst` zone in Orchard CMS.

As far as I'm concerned there is no need to create your own zones, it could be done via your own `Content Definition` and creating your own View for Menu widget. It that correct, can you please share some info about it?

BTW: How do I add my custom View for replacing some widgets? Should I simply add `.cshtml` file with proper naming?

Comment: Download the shape tracing tool, found here: http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.DesignerTools and use it to inspect your menus to find the correct names for alternate shapes to use. These will be created in your custom theme.

Comment: Did it, can you please also mention how do I suppose to add to project, I've tries to add Views/Parts/Widget-SideBar.cshtml but nothing worked. If you'll answer I'd able to mark your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the shape tracing tool, found here: gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/… and use it to inspect your menus to find the correct names for alternate shapes to use. These will be created in your enabled theme.

I believe you can copy the view generated by Shape Tracing into one of your modules and place it in the Views folder, not Views/Parts/.

Comment: Thanks, so shape tracing tool can generate views? Seems I've missed this option, should check it once again.

Comment: Yeah, tis a very useful feature :) Designing Orchard sites would be next to impossible without it

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot. Found it. Can you please also clarify, how can I add another menu widget to aside first zone? I need to display two different menus there.

Comment: You can add the menu from the widgets section in the admin area